Why my multipage React app dont show my pages?
It`s my first React project and i want to make a multi page app for my BackEnd API, but none of my pages appear on the Screen
App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Main from './pages/Panel';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/app" element={<Main />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}


pages/Login.jsx
import React from 'react';

export function Login() {
    return(
        <>
            <h1>Login Screen</h1>   
            <h2>Start</h2>     
            <p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaa</p>
            <p>Test</p>
        </>        
    )
}


main.jsx
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)


My friend try to solve this and in his computer its working fine but when i got the commit he made still doesn't change anything, i am using Vite and this is the only parts of the code that i modify expect the css files and the another page i try to make work out

Where did you deploy your project? Does your project working on your computer?

my project works on my computer, its just the pages, when i add a  to the index.html works fine, but if i add to the main.jsx or the app.jsx doenst work


if you add a <p> to the index.html works fine, but in app.jsx doesn't work.
check, is module direct in src/main.jsx ?
